# pyo.iplot(fig) not showing pie chart diagram

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to use plotly to try and generate a piechart. For some reason it doesn't seem to be appearing after i put in the pyo.iplot(fig) or even a plot.show() command.
It doesn't seem to be showing any errors and produces a large amount of code after i use the pyo.iplot(fig) command shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I have done some slight research into how to maybe change the setup phrase at the start of the code as i thought that might be causing some problems but i haven't found anything.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import get_ipython
ipy = get_ipython()
if ipy is not None:
    ipy.run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
pyo.offline.init_notebook_mode()
```

The problematic parts could potentially be the "pyo.offline.init_notebook_mode()" or possibly 
something to do with the "import plotly.offline as pyo"

Here is also the chart code just in case that could also be it: It is a pie chart.

```
labels = df['Gender'].value_counts().index
values = df['Gender'].value_counts().values
colors = ['#eba796', '#96ebda']
fig = {'data' : [{'type' : 'pie',
                  'name' : "Patients by Gender: Pie chart",
                 'labels' : df['Gender'].value_counts().index,
                 'values' : df['Gender'].value_counts().values,
                 'direction' : 'clockwise',
                 'marker' : {'colors' : ['#9cc359', '#e96b5c']}}], 'layout' : {'title' : 'Patients by Gender'}}

pyo.iplot(fig)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please attach some sample data? Also, are you running a Jupiter notebook?

Comment: No, this is in python.

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular it will be great to add (at leasta  sample of) the data you want to plot.

Comment: Then it seems to me that you are tying to use an old syntax. Since version 4.0 plotly is offline only so you can skip all the offline related lines.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to set the [default renderer](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#setting-the-default-renderer). For example if you would like to show the figure in your default web browser:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'
```